# Conditionally selecting two columns

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

Here's the Data in my spreadsheet:

```
colA   colB
NYC    USA
NYC    USA
ROC    USA
SEA    USA
YVR    CAN
YYZ    CAN
LON    UK
LON    CAN
LON    USA
```

How do I get the data for the following rule:

Get all the cities and countries, for which there is more than 1 unique combination of city+country. In other words, extract only those cities (along with respective countries), which have more than one country.

From the above data, I'm looking to get the following result:

```
LON  UK
LON  CAN
LON  USA
```

because LON is the only one which occurs more than 1 once in different countries.

Tried COUNTIF, UNIQUE, QUERY and none of them produce the result I hope for, because I know I'm not using them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you would get the list of such cities by doing:

```
select city
from t
group by city
having min(country) <> max(country);
```

However, if you want the original rows, I would instead use `exists`:

```
select city, country
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.city = t.city and t2.country <> t.country);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `QUERY` function as

```
=QUERY("SELECT ColA, ColB WHERE Col1='colA'"
  QUERY(
       QUERY(
             Data!A1:B10,
            "SELECT colA, count(distinct ColB) GROUP BY ColA"
            ), 
        "WHERE Col2 > 1")
      )
```

*where `Col2` is case-sensitive and should be written as initcapped as this.*